# ASCII value for enter/return

Tags: keyboard, return, arduino, ascii, carriage-return

I am working on a paper keyboard using barepaint and arduino leonardo.
Every key works fine so far, except the return key.

This is how the code looks for one button:

```
if (button5 > 1000)
  {
    Keyboard.write(120);
  }
```

But I can't seem to find the ASCII value for the key, return. 
I know it's some sort of a combination, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Arduino documation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardModifiers) for the Keyboard library lists 176 as mapping to `KEY_ENTER'.

The [source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HID.cpp) maps ASCII 10 to ENTER and does not map ASCII 13 to anything.

Internally both 176 and 10 map to the USB HID keyboard value 40 (decimal).

According to http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/Hut1_11.pdf‎ 40 maps to "Keyboard Enter" (as opposed to "Keypad Enter")

So use either 176 or 10 they should do the same thing.